# PrimeFaces 4.0 Tree ActionListener

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 4.0 with JSF 2.0

i have a tree and i want to perform specific action on the child node not on the parent node, my code is like:

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeBean.embargoRoot}" var="node" animate="true" >
            <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
            <p:commandButton value="#{node}" action="#{xmlReader.getRead()}"  id="treeNode"/>  
        </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
    </h:form>'
```

Tree Class

```
    public TreeClass(){
            root = new DefaultTreeNode("", null);
        TreeNode p1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Parent 1", root);
        TreeNode p2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Parent 2", root);
        TreeNode c1= new DefaultTreeNode("Child 1", p1);
        TreeNode c2= new DefaultTreeNode("Child 2", p1);

            TreeNode c3= new DefaultTreeNode("Child 1", p2);
        TreeNode c4= new DefaultTreeNode("child 2", p2);
}
```

my aim is to perform specific task on child click only

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selection option for "p:tree"

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeBean.embargoRoot}" selectionMode="single"  
     selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}"var="node" animate="true" >
        <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
            <p:commandButton value="#{node}" action="#{xmlReader.getRead()}"  id="treeNode"/>  
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

Depending on what you need to do here is an ajax update on event:

```
<p:ajax event="select" update=":form:objects"/>  
<p:ajax event="unselect" update=":form:objects"/>
```

It is also possible to execute bean operations with getter/setters but not recommended.